# URI::InvalidURIError - ONLY when directory is stored in a Dropbox folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropbox

Since moving my rails app project directory to a folder synchronised by Dropbox, I am getting an error on the following line of app/views/layouts/application.html

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

The error message displayed is as follows (directory/project names modified for privacy):

```
bad URI(is not URI?): file-digest:///Volumes/Internal HDD/Dropbox/ClientName/Apps/Project Folder Name/project-name/app/assets/config
```

As soon as I move the project directory (project-name) onto the desktop (not synced by dropbox) the error goes away - even though all code is identical.

I did notice [another post similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287113/bad-uri-on-rails-javascript-include-tag-and-stylesheet-link-tag), but there was no real answer on why.  I would really like to be able to store the project in dropbox, just so that all of my work files are all together in one place, and so I can keep certain gitignored files such as secrets.yml for api keys synced across devices.

Thanks.

Comment: (I am using macOS if that information has any relevance)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this issue? I am having this exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

This exact issue happened to me today.  This solution solved it for me:  https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Installation-and-desktop-app/undo-changed-folder-name/td-p/220463

In my case, I have a Personal Dropbox and a Business Dropbox account.  When you link your Business Dropbox account to your computer after having a linked personal Dropbox account, Dropbox renames your "Dropbox" folder to "Dropbox (Personal)" and also creates a "Dropbox (Company Name)" folder for your Business Dropbox.

After a while, I decided I didn't want my Dropbox Business account to be linked to my Mac anymore, so I unlinked it.  However, after unlinking, my personal Dropbox folder remained named "Dropbox (Personal)".

Then when I bought a second Mac, and linked my personal Dropbox to it, Dropbox named the folder the normal "Dropbox".  This created an inconsistency between my new Mac (which had a "Dropbox" folder) and my older Mac (which had a "Dropbox (Personal)" folder).

Following the instructions linked above allowed me to rename my older mac's dropbox folder back to "Dropbox" so that the two are the same.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the solution for me as the root folder is called 'Dropbox' on all my devices.  Thanks for the suggestion anyway - hope this helps someone else.